# Odoo: I can't validate invoices from Accounting(admin user only)

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to validate an invoice from Accounting with the admin user but it gives me an error:

> field(s) `company_id` failed against a constraint: Account and Period must belong to the same company.

Account and period belong to the same company and if I log in with another user I can validate the Invoice, but for some reason I can't with admin. I even tried to duplicate the user admin, and it works, but with the real one don't.

I'm messing right now with the access rights but for the moment I got nothing.
Any ideas?

Thanks for your time

Comment: It's very hard to answer this question. Whether there is not enough information (example values) or there is another question: did you install custom modules? If there is no programming context, this question doesn't belong to SO. Maybe use Odoo's help forum.

Comment: See I have updated answer that may helps you. Recently I have faced that issue so I have updated the conclusion here.

Answer (score 0):

While you validate invoice it will create account move entry for that invoice in which the following things will be affected and anyone of them belongs to different company then it won't allowed you to validate invoice. This scenario happens with Admin user only because admin have access to all companies records and record rules are getting by passed for admin. For normal user other company data will be hidden by rules (multi company rule).

All these records must belongs to same company.

> - **Product Account** => Generally set automatically while you    select product.
> - **Tax** => Tax which are there in invoice line (in most of cases with    admin user tax selected of the other company because admin
>     have    access to all companies. And tax will be set automatically while product onchange fired.)
> - **Debtor Account / Journal Accounts** => Customer receivable account or    debit/credit accounts of journal of invoice.

If above all cases are correct then you need to verify only one thing that is accounting period. Account period which is selected in that invoice and accounts (debit and credit) in account journal both are not belongs to same company. There is reason to select account period of another company in invoice because ADMIN user have access to all companies. So first period will be selected in invoice (it will never go to check for company if user is admin) and if user is not admin then other companies record will not be loaded this is why it's always working for normal user but not for admin (because access rules are by pass for admin user).

Comment: Very interesting.